# Could this circuit cause the MCU to fail?

Tags: microcontroller, led, output

I drive a common-cathode three digit 7-segment display ([JSD-2832AUR](http://www.jstronic.com/uploads/2019529112458264.pdf)) with an MCU ([TM4C123GH6PGE](https://www.ti.com/product/TM4C123GH6PGE?keyMatch=TM4C123GH6PGE)).

The circuit looks as follows:
[image]

Distribution of the signals on the MCU ports:
[image]

All `7SEG_*` signals are directly connected to output pins of the MCU. The supply voltage is 3.3 V.

At any given time only one of the common-cathode pins (`7SEG_DIG1`, `7SEG_DIG2`, `7SEG_DIG3`) are driven LOW.
For this measurement I'm driving all anode pins (`7SEG_a`, .., `7SEG_DP`) with a permanent HIGH signal, and switch the three cathode pins periodically.

DCO plot:
[image]

Measurements:
[image]

If these were driven by hard signals (0 V, 3.3 V) instead of the output of an MCU, the current per LED would be:

\$I_{LED} = \frac{V_{DD} - V_{LED}}{R} = \frac{3.3V - 2.0V}{150Ω} = 8.667mA\$

Calculating the current using the measured values:

\$I_{LED} = \frac{V_R}{R} = \frac{3.24V - 3.09V}{150Ω} = 1mA\$

**My question:**
As can be seen in the DCO plot, when the cathode-signal is pulled LOW, the actual voltage is 1.37 V. Could this pose a problem for the microcontroller? Could this cause the MCU to fail? Nothing gets hot, not even slightly. But we have some random MCU failures[‡] occurring, so I'm considering every possibility.

[‡] With MCU failure I mean that the MCU is totally dead (the internal core 1.2 V LDO and the oscillator both remain at 0 V). It's not typical for this MCU family to be so fragile. We're using the TM4C family for years, and if anything, we've come to the conclusion that they're very robust.

---

**EDIT: additional info from the comments***

The drive strength of all MCU outputs is 8 mA:

```c
// config 7SEG_a .. 7SEG_f outputs
MAP_GPIODirModeSet(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7), GPIO_DIR_MODE_OUT);
MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7), GPIO_STRENGTH_8MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD);
MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7));
MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7), 0);

// config 7SEG_g .. 7SEG_DP outputs
MAP_GPIODirModeSet(GPIO_PORTC_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5), GPIO_DIR_MODE_OUT);
MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTC_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5), GPIO_STRENGTH_8MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD);
MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTC_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5));
MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTC_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5), 0);

// config 7SEG_DIG1 .. 7SEG_DIG3 outputs
MAP_GPIODirModeSet(GPIO_PORTH_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2), GPIO_DIR_MODE_OUT);
MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTH_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2), GPIO_STRENGTH_8MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD);
MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTH_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2));
MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTH_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2), (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2));
```

`7SEG_a` to `7SEG_f` are connected to PORT_A.
`7SEG_g` and `7SEG_DP` are connected to PORT_C.
`7SEG_DIG1` to `7SEG_DIG3` are connected to PORT_H.

I have evaluated the "per-side" current limits on the datasheet, for example (section 24.3). We're far below the maximum ratings.

Approximately 15% of all devices failed. Tbh, it could be a bad batch of MCUs. But that's not the first option I want to consider.
They don't fail immediately, usually after a couple of weeks. All of these cases are from a single production batch of 200 pieces.

---

*TM4C123GH6PGE digital output specifications:*

[image]

[image]
<sup>Source: [TM4C123GH6PGE Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pge.pdf)</sup>

---

*JSD-2832AUR specifications:*

[image]

[image]

[image]
<sup>Source: [JSD-2832AUR Datasheet](http://www.jstronic.com/uploads/2019529112458264.pdf)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure you're allowing enough time between turning one digit off and turning the next one on?

Comment: "MCU failure I mean that the MCU is totally dead" do you mean the individual chip never works again, or doesn't work until power-cycled?

Comment: Is the blue plot C3?  Wouldn't we expect this to be either 0V or 3V3.

Comment: The problem could be outside this circuit so posting a new question with full schematics may be more beneficial.

Comment: @jonathanjo Why do you expect those values? MCU IO pins are not superconductors, they are relatively weak driving DC currents.

Comment: @justme Isn't C3  `7SEG_DIG1`? and OP says "At any given time only one of the common-cathode pins (7SEG_DIG1, 7SEG_DIG2, 7SEG_DIG3) are driven LOW."

Comment: @jonathanjo Yes, and when it's low, it needs to sink current, and so the voltage can't be 0V. At the weakest drive strength setting, datasheet guarantees it can sink at least 2mA before voltage reaches 0.4V.

Comment: @Finbarr Yes, I'm sure the timing isn't an issue. The LED display looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @justme my understanding is that we're getting about 8 mA through 7SEG_DIG1; I'm wondering what its drive setting is.

Comment: @jonathanjo With 'dead', I mean effectively dead, as in the 1.2V LDO doesn't power up and the OSC doesn't run. Also after a power cycle.

Comment: @jonathanjo Yes the blue plot is C3. That's the point, it doesn't go to 0V as expeted.

Comment: "some random MCU failures" -- any estimate of what percentage or any other characterisation?

Comment: @Justme Yes, the problem of the fried MCUs could be something other than the LED display. The main differences from the product that has this issue is the LED display. And the power supply. I'm also verifying the power supply.

Comment: Per @justme's observation about issues outside of this section of the circuit ... is the MCU driving much else?  I notice the "per-side" limits on the datasheet, for example (section 24.3)

Comment: @jonathanjo _"any estimate of what percentage or any other characterisation?"_ Approximately 15% of all devices failed. Tbh, it *could* be a bad batch of MCUs. But that's not the first option I want to consider.

Comment: @jonathanjo _"I notice the "per-side" limits on the datasheet, for example (section 24.3)"_ I've verified these values. We're far from the max rating. Most of the remaining pins are configured as inputs or for communication (SPI, CAN, USB). But nothing that draws much current.

Comment: How long are the conductors going to the display?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany _"How long are the conductors going to the display?"_ About 25mm / 1 inch

Comment: 15% sounds like an awful lot.  Do they fail immediately, eventually, randomly?  Bad batch of something is possible of course, but I'd guess trouble in assembly, soldering, PCB or even resistors and LEDs before the MCU.   Have you checked in SW the drive strength?  I note in manual "By default, all GPIO pins have 2-mA drive" (`GPIODR2R`)

Comment: @jonathanjo We're considering troubles in assembly, soldering, PCB, and components. But haven't found anything glaringly obvious so far. I'm actively configuring a drive strength of 8mA.

Comment: Have you checked the resistor values?  For example, if they are marked 150 they could be 15Ω rather than 150Ω.

Comment: Obviously we don't know how complex your code is; but I'd be wondering if there's any possibility something buggy is overwriting the 8mA settting ... which would make me want to try (on the bench) configuring 2mA on purpose and see if it recreates the 1V37 measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the single measurement for one resistor can be assumed to hold true for all resistors and LEDs, there will be 1mA for each LED and as each digit has max 8 LEDs then max 8mA total current can flow into cathode drive pin.

That's certainly within absolute maximum ratings.

In the recommended limits it says the pin should be able to drive at least 8mA with 0.4V voltage in 8mA drive mode, and with relaxed IO parameters, in 8mA drive mode it can drive at least 18mA with a voltage of 1.2V.

Your measurements indicate the values are clearly nowhere near the expected 8mA drive mode values, if there's already 1.37V with 8mA current.

So while I don't see how this could be a problem, the MCU pin drive strength does seem to be set incorrectly and you should set all the LED anode and cathode drive pins to highest strength, just to be sure and rule out it is not a problem.

Perhaps also measure all voltages in the LED circuit to determine that no excessive currents flow accidentally. This also includes verifying with a multimeter that all the resistor are really 150 ohms instead of something else.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I already configured all of these pins for a drive strength of 8 mA. The part I don't understand is how the voltage rises to 0.4V and 1.2V when sinking 8mA and 18mA, respectively. And if this could have some implications for my problem (because the voltage reaches 1.37V).

Comment: @Velvel If resistors are really 150 ohms, total current really 8mA, and drive stregth really set to 8mA, then the IO pin voltage should not be 1.37V. Double check everything, for schematic errors, and then for PCB design errors, and then PCB manufacture errors, and then errors in component BOM and then errors in pick&place. For example if any supply or ground pins are left unconnected on PCB or some ferrite bead is missing to half of the MCU is unpowered or bypass caps missing on MCU built-in LDO, glitches on regulator that powers MCU, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers and comments, I'm 100% sure that I wasn't operating the microcontroller within specs. And thus it could very possibly be the cause of the MCU deaths.

I measured \$V_{LED,anode}\$, which is an MCU output pulled LOW (current sink).

[image]

[image]

As @Justme answered *"it can drive at least 18mA with a [low] voltage of 1.2V."*

[image]

I've now modified the firmware to only allow 2 active segments at any given time.

A single segment is (theoretically) the equivalent of ~8.9mA. The datasheet specifies that any 4 outputs may source or sink up to 18mA (when configured as 8mA outputs). So with two active segments, I'm still below this threshold.

Only further tests will show whether this is actually the cause of the problem.